# Exclude or set a unique color to the bottom triangle of a correlation matrix heatmap

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I have created a correlation matrix of the mtcars dataset in plotly with:

```
# Load data
data("mtcars")
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
# print the first 6 rows
head(my_data, 6)
res <- cor(my_data)
round(res, 2)
plot_ly(x=colnames(res), y=rownames(res), z = res, type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis=list(tickfont = list(size = 30), tickangle = 45),
    margin = list(l = 150, r = 50, b = 150, t = 0, pad = 4))
```

However I was instructed that I shouldn't be displaying the symmetrical, full heatmap, because it contains 50% redundant information (the top and bottom triangles above and below the diagonal have symmetrical, opposite values). If there is an option within the heatmap plotting package that we're using, to grey out (display as a single, uniform grey color) the bottom half of the heatmap.For example:

[image]

Comment: I've made an attempt but it fails. Maybe you or someone could find a way to tweak it and possibly let me know how to make it work. This is the said function but I can't seem to figure out how to tweak it. `color_function<-function(x){
  cols<-c("purple","gray","indianred4","yellow")
  
      i<-findInterval(x,c(-2,0.2,1))
      cols[i]
    
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to not use the complete correlation dataset and filter out only one half of the matrix using `upper.tri`. You could even consider setting its `diag` argument to `TRUE` to get rid of the arguably unnecessary diagonal ones.

How about the below?

```
# Load data
library(plotly)
data("mtcars")
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
# print the first 6 rows
head(my_data, 6)
res <- cor(my_data)
res[upper.tri(res)] <- NA
round(res, 2)
plot_ly(x=colnames(res), y=rownames(res), z = res, type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis=list(tickfont = list(size = 30), tickangle = 45),
    margin = list(l = 150, r = 50, b = 150, t = 0, pad = 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Does that keep the correlations?

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, the (unique) correlations are untouched as can be seen by printing out the `res` object.

Comment: I think by setting them as "NA", you've basically removed them.

Comment: Yes, but the other half of the matrix contains exactly the same numbers as the ones NA'd